# Running telnet from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, telnet

As some of you are well-aware, you can watch Star wars IV in ASCII text bu running the following in CMD

```
telnet
o
towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

I was wondering if you could run this from a batch file. I know this question may be very "noobish" however I have tried stuff like

```
telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

and

```
telnet -o towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

also

```
start telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

and none of them work. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows?  I think `telnet.exe` is removed in more recent versions, so you'll have to install something.

Comment: `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl` worked here. Type `telnet /?` for what you can put on command line. (in telnet type `?`). Telnet is available to be turned on in Windows Features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start "" telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

The person who answered this seems to have deleted their answer so I am posting this so other people who have this problem can look here

Comment: You don't really need the empty string there, but you can use it to specify a title for the new command prompt window, if you wish.